# Using schtasks in interactive mode

Tags: passwords, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to create a scheduled task from the command line, in interactive mode. The `at hh:mm /interactive program` command fails, stating that security policies do not allow interactive execution.

I'd therefore like to use the schtasks command. But when I type something like

```
schtasks  /Create /TN MyTask /SC DAILY /ST "13:10" /TR "notepad.exe" /V1 /F
```

I get a message asking for my password, although I haven't set a password for my session. And when I leave the field blank, the command line answers that the task won't be able to run.

How can I fix this problem? And how can I make the task interactive? Using `/RU SYSTEM` prevents the task from being run in interactive mode.

Thanks!
CFP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:
at `date -d "now + 2 minutes" +%H:%M` /interactive "notepad.exe"

Of course you'll need to tweak the time and other options but this should work, starting the task under the system account by default, and interacting with the desktop.